# Python: Remove Leading and Trailing zero and corresponding time values from a time-series

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series

I have a time series data, e.g

```
y = [0, 0 , 0 , 0.45, 0, 0.89, 0.78, 0, 0]
t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I want to remove the leading and trailing zeros from this data also remove the corresponding time values. The output should look like:

```
y_0removed = [0.45, 0, 0.89, 0.78]
new_t = [4,5,6,7]
```

I tried, numpy.trim(), str.strip() functions but they only work on the y values.

Also, tried this function, didn't give an output.

```
def remove_zeros(counts, time):
# Remove both
  for i in range(len(counts)):
    while str(counts[i])[0] == "0":
      counts[i] = str(counts[i])[1:]
    while str(counts[i])[-1] == "0":
      counts[i] = str(counts[i])[:-1]
    bothremoved.append(counts[i])
    dt.append(time[i])
    
    return [bothremoved, time]

y = [0, 0 , 0 , 0.45, 0, 0.89, 0.78, 0, 0]
t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]


print(y, t)
print(remove_zeros(y, t))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach for the same:

```
y = [0, 0 , 0 , 0.45, 0, 0.89, 0.78, 0, 0]
t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    
start = None
end = None
# Get the start and end index
for index, element in enumerate(y):
    if element != 0 and not start:
        start = str(index)
        end = str(index)
        continue
    if element != 0 and start:
        end = str(index)
        
# Slice both the lists using the obtained start and end indices
y_removed = y[int(start): int(end)+1]
t = t[int(start): int(end)+1]
print (y_removed)
print (t)
```

Output:

```
[0.45, 0, 0.89, 0.78]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your remove_zeroes is a bit confused, there's no need to be converting into strings, and checking the first index of the string will return wrong results for eg `0.45` ("0" is the first character). And as far as I can tell, dt doesn't exist.

You want to

- Find the index of the first nonzero value of counts
- Find the index of the last nonsero value of counts
- Trim both arrays to these indices

A simple implementation might be

```
def remove_zeroes(counts, time):
    # Find the index of the first nonzero value
    for i in range(len(counts)):
        if counts[i] != 0:
             break
    # Find the index of the last nonzero value
    # (Iterate from the end of the list to the 0th element)
    for j in range(len(counts) - 1, -1, -1):
        if counts[j] != 0:
             break
    if j < i: # There are no nonzero values
        return [], []
    return counts[i:j+1], time[i:j+1]
```

This should work without numpy. If you're using numpy, there are probably some clever vectorizing solutions you can do, if you expect this to be a particularly time-consuming part of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I understand the confusion. This works perfectly